# Show attribute values on Woocommerce category archive pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

In a Wordpress + Woocommerce website I have a menu with some custom links that recall specific shop pages URLs using advanced queries taxonomies.

These are example links I use for these custom menu entries:

```
https://example.com/product-category/cat1/?pa_attrib1=value1&pa_attrib2=value3
https://example.com/product-category/cat2/?pa_attrib1=value2&pa_attrib3=value4`
https://example.com/product-category/cat2/?pa_attrib1=value5&pa_attrib4=value5,value7,value8,value9
```

In this way I can configure "direct" entries to the various shop departments.

Now **I need to show, in the shop and archive page, the name and the values of the attributes set in the url** in a similar way:

> *Category Name - Attribute 1 name: value1 - Atttribute 2 Name: value2, ...*

I suppose I need to use the hook **woocommerce_archive_description** in functions.php but I don't know how recall and show the values I need

```
add_action ( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'show_term_description', 20 );
function show_term_description() {
   echo term_description( $term_id, $taxonomy ); // print Category Name
   // ...
   // ...
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with the following commented code inserted in your hooked function:

```
add_action ( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'show_term_description', 20 );
function show_term_description() {
    // Only for product category archive pages
    if( ! is_product_category()) return;

    global $wp;

    // Get the requested Url category/subcategories
    $request = $wp->request;
    // Set them in an array
    $request = explode( '/', $request );

    // Remove 'product-category' from the array
    if( 'product-category' == $request[0] )
        unset($request[0]);

    // Starting html formatting
    $html = '<p><strong>';

    // The main category and sub-categories names
    foreach( $request as $category ){
        // Get the category name
        $category_term = get_term_by( 'slug', $category, 'product_cat' );
        // Set category and subcategories in an array
        $categories_name[] = $category_term->name;
    }
    // Formatting the category/subcategories in an html string
    $html .= implode( '</strong> - <strong>', $categories_name );

    // The product attributes names and related values
    if( ! empty($_GET) ){
        $html .= '</strong> - <strong>'; // Formatting html
        $count = 0; // Initializing the counter
        $attr_count = count($_GET); // get the length of the array
        // Loop through the attribute/values from the $_GET
        foreach($_GET as $taxonomy => $values ){
            $count++;
            $terms_names = array(); // Initializing

            // If the taxonomy doesn't exist,
            if( ! taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy ) ){
                continue; // We go to next attribute
            }

            // Set the attribute terms in an array
            $term_slugs = explode( ',', $values );
            // Loop through the attribute term
            foreach( $term_slugs as $term_slug ){
                // Get the WP_Term object
                $term = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomy );
                if( ! term_exists( $term->term_id, $taxonomy ) )
                continue; // We go to next term

                // Set The term name in an array
                $terms_names[] = $term->name;
            }
            // If there is no corresponding terms for the taxonomy
            if( sizeof($terms_names) == 0 ){
                continue; // We go to next attribute
            }

            // Add the attribute label name to the output
            if( $count > 1 ) $html .= ' - ';
            $html .= wc_attribute_label( $taxonomy );
            // Formatting the term names in a string and add them to the output
            $html .= ':</strong> ' . implode( ', ', $terms_names) . '<strong>';
        }
    }
    // Outputing The html
    echo $html.'</p>';
    echo $attr_count .' | '.$count;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works…

Comment: hello,

I see that this code is not working anymore: is it possible that the lasts WooCommerce versions have broken it?

Comment: @Giovanni May be... This code has been donne for a prior version of woocommerce and was perfectly working. I will try to find out what is wrong with it in the last version of Woocommerce.

Comment: @Giovanni I have tested that code in Woocommerce last version 3.4.2 and **it's still working fine as before.** Now I have made an update, To be sure that the product attributes exist and that the attributes terms exists for those product  attributes, avoiding output errors, when Url arguments mismatch.

Comment: thanks. It's strange because in my website is not working. I check better.